# Again, QT 5.12.2 QMYSQL driver not loaded. The libraries are though

Tags: windows, qt, visual-studio-2019

Visual Studio 2019 Professional, retargeted qt project for qt 5.12.2 (Qt\5.12.2\msvc2017_64).
Trying to connect to a MySQL DB, although the files

qsqlmysqld.dll and
libmysql.dll

get loaded the output I get is

> QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL3 driver not loaded QSqlDatabase: available
> drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7
>
> Could not connect

What could be wrong this time?

edit: for clarification purposes that's the output I get

> 'Current Project' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Qt\5.12.2\msvc2017_64\plugins\sqldrivers\qsqlmysqld.dll'.
>
> 'Current Project' (Win32): Loaded '....\libmysql.dll'.

So it's true that it doesn't load the libmysqld.dll library.
Something else that is unclear to me is the Win32 in the parentheses, as I have x64 selected.

I have tried both x86 and x64 versions of libmysql.dll but it didn't work.
Furthermore running dumpbin to identify library dependencies it seems that everything is there

Comment: How do you know they are loaded? The names suggest you might be mixing release and debug mode libs? (With "d" prefix and without)

Comment: True.. That's a nice notice... but that's the output I get    


>'Current Project' (Win32): Loaded ....\sqldrivers\qsqlmysqld.dll'. 
>'Current Project' (Win32): Loaded ....\debug\libmysql.dll'.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution but with some compromises.
First and foremost **we cannot debug**, oracle won't allow. So we need to make sure that it's a release configuration.

In order for the application to run we need to copy within the folder where the executable is the x64 bit version of **libmysql.dll**. But this is not enough 
This dll has some dependencies that seem to be different between versions, so in order to find them I had to run the **dumpbin** command with the /dependents flag. For my case and version the mysql server included dlls where

> libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll

and

> libssl-1_1-x64.dll

After that I could successfully make queries to the instance of the Mysql Server